Sometimes bot can't mention user by Number ID
I am programming an Telegram bot by using of python-telegram-bot 21.1.1 and bot must mentions accounts which start bot, in my PV as Admin and lets me know.
But sometimes bot doesn't mention users and just sends the word in [ ], without any user mention.
I know bot can't mention users that haven't started bot. I'm talking about users that have started bot.
like my 2nd telegram account. I tested some different accounts and different bots. My code is something like that:
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, ContextTypes

TOKEN = ""

async def start(update: Update , context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    IDUser = update.message.from_user.id
    # IDUser = "1234567890" # my 2nd account ID
    sendMessageTo = "my account that is Admin"
    await context.bot.sendMessage(sendMessageTo , f"[User](tg://user?id={IDUser}) with this IntegerID `{IDUser}` started Bot" , parse_mode='MarkdownV2')
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = ApplicationBuilder().token(TOKEN).build()
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    print('Polling')
    app.run_polling(poll_interval=3)

I tested putting ID of any chat (Personal, Group, Channel) instead of sendMessageTo.  Any bot couldn't mention my 2nd account in my PV or groups that my 2nd account isn't a member of. Then I tested in groups that it's a member of and its own PV, and bot could mention it in these chats. Finally in channels and bot could mentions it in channel when it's a member of channel and also when it's not a member of channel.
I thought it might be like that for every account. I tested this too, and it wasn't.
This same result is for two different bots that made by different telegram accounts in BotFather.
I have set IDUser equal to my 2nd account ID for testing that bot mentions it when sends the message to anyone.
It's my 2nd account username: @someone_2nd. I can start your bot by, for testing and solving my problem by you.
In addition I remember bot had mentioned my 2nd account in group properly, about 2 weeks ago and there is proof for. This problem has arisen yesterday or its past day.
